# MySQL munging username on linux

Tags: mysql, linux

I'm writing a script to perform some database maintenance, and MySQL is not accepting the username I'm trying to pass it.

I have a MySQL user and database named 'abc_wpsites', as well as a user and database named 'abc_wpsitesdev'.  Here, I'm trying to access abc_wpsitesdev, but MySQL continually attempts to access with the account 'abc_wpsites' instead.

```
abc.com [~]# mysql -uabc_wpsitesdev --password='(redacted)' -h localhost abc_wpsitesdev
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'abc_wpsites'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
abc.com [~]# mysql --user='abc_wpsitesdev' --password='(redacted)' -h localhost abc_wpsitesdev
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'abc_wpsites'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
abc.com [~]# mysql --user='abc_wpsitesfff' --password='(redacted)' -h localhost abc_wpsitesdev
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'abc_wpsites'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Notice how each attempt at experimenting with the username still results in an attempt to access MySQL via the 'abc_wpsites' account.  Any thoughts on what's going on here?

---

Also, I should mention that I can connect via other methods with the appropriate credentials (e.g. via MySQL), so this seems to be some sort of problem with my understanding/the operation of MySQL's CLI interface.

Comment: Using authentication plugins / proxy users maybe?

Comment: Good thought - Unfortunately, this is a very vanilla use-case (not using any plugins/proxy users).  So very strange!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest passing your login information that way.  This means your password is

- Visible in the processlist (some distro's will filter that but)
- It's either stored in a crontab or your bash .history file

Instead create at script.cnf file that is NOT world readable.

The contents will look like

```
[client]
user=abc_wspitesdev
password=your_password
```

Change your command line call to

mysql --defaults-file=/path/to/script.cnf -h localhost abc_wpsitesdev
mysql

**Edit**

Your other comment said you could connect as other users.  If you have root access to this db run

select user, host, passowrd from mysql.users;

Compare the one that's not working with others that are.

The passwords that are stored will be hashes of the actual values.  Are they all the same length?  If one is significantly longer or shorter it could be the password was stored with an old password hashing method used in versions 4.x and earlier.

What is the host for the account you are trying to connect through?  Is it 'localhost' or an IP address?  If it is your IP address this likely might be the problem.  Since your command line call is connecting to localhost this will tell it to connect through a unix socket (/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock perhaps).  MySQL differentiates these connections from ones coming through the TCP stack.

You could alternatively specify your full (non 127.0.0.1) IP address on the commandline if this is the case like

mysql -u blah -pblah -h 1.2.3.4

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  Do you have any idea why this is happening?  I fear that even if I do rewrite our scripts to use a .cnf file as you recommend, the same issue will occur.

Comment: If you do not specify the password in the command line, but let it prompt you for the password, is your login then accepted?

Comment: Good idea; just tried it.  Nope. :/

Comment: Justed edited my response for more details

Comment: I just tried using the .cnf file, and the error persists.  I would check the password length as you recommend, but I definitely can connect via other methods with the appropriate credentials (e.g. via MySQL).

Also, I'm just connecting via localhost.  I'm starting to think this is just a bug. :/

Answer (score 0):

"Where" is user "abc_wpsitesdev" allowed to connect from as opposed to where the "abc_wpsites" user is allowed to connect from -- any difference?

If you did "grant all privileges on abcwpsitedev to 'abc_wpsitesdev'@'%' identified by 'thedevpassword';" that won't work for accessing from localhost as explained in the last pargraph in the post from the manual below:

From the MySQL manual:

After connecting to the server as root, you can add new accounts. The following statements use GRANT to set up four new accounts:

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost'
    ->     IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass' WITH GRANT OPTION;

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%'
    ->     IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass' WITH GRANT OPTION;

mysql> GRANT RELOAD,PROCESS ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';

mysql> GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'dummy'@'localhost';

The accounts created by these statements have the following properties:

Two of the accounts have a user name of monty and a password of some_pass. Both accounts are superuser accounts with full privileges to do anything. The 'monty'@'localhost' account can be used only when connecting from the local host. The 'monty'@'%' account uses the '%' wildcard for the host part, so it can be used to connect from any host.

It is necessary to have both accounts for monty to be able to connect from anywhere as monty. Without the localhost account, the anonymous-user account for localhost that is created by mysql_install_db would take precedence when monty connects from the local host. As a result, monty would be treated as an anonymous user. The reason for this is that the anonymous-user account has a more specific Host column value than the 'monty'@'%' account and thus comes earlier in the user table sort order. (user table sorting is discussed in Section 5.5.4, “Access Control, Stage 1: Connection Verification”.)

Comment: Both databases are indentical with regard to "where" they can be allowed to connect from.

Answer (score -1):

the problem with your line

```
mysql -uabc_wpsitesdev --password='(redacted)' -h localhost abc_wpsitesdev
```

is, that you need a space after -u
(and no space after -p)

this is the form I use:

```
mysql -u abc_wpsitesdev -p(redacted) -h localhost abc_wpsitesdev
```

Comment: A space is not necessary after `-u`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still doesn't work.  The MySQL command is properly formed and works fine for other usernames, just not for this one. :/